# Навести "фокус" на поле ввода

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот смотрю с помощью `DevTools` - `html` код элемента "поля ввода":

```
<span class="Textinput Textinput_view_big-input Textinput_size_l">
<input type="text" data-t="field:input-login" dir="ltr" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="username" class="Textinput-Control" id="passp-field-login" name="login" placeholder="Логин или email" value=""><span class="Textinput-Box"></span></span>
```

Навожу "фокус" с помощью обычной функции:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("Textinput-Control")[0].focus()
```

И все работает. Меня интересует, а как понять, что работать будет именно с именем класса - `Textinput-Control`, а не с `Textinput Textinput_view_big-input Textinput_size_l` ?

Почему с `Textinput Textinput_view_big-input Textinput_size_l` - не хочет работать `focus()` ?

Comment: потому что селекторы надо правильно писать и применять методы соответсвующие...  и явно не getElementsByClassName в таком случае

Comment: Я может чего-то не знаю, но разве при фокусе `span`-a должен фокус попадать на `input` ?)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, а в таком случае - это в каком ?

Comment: "Textinput Textinput_view_big-input Textinput_size_l"  вот в таком

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете ввиду под "а как понять, что работать будет именно с именем класса - Textinput-Control, а не с Textinput Textinput_view_big-input Textinput_size_l ?"
Если вопрос заключается в том, почему вы не можете сфокусироваться на <span>, то ответ: потому, что span не является фокусируемым элементом по умолчанию.
К фокусируемым элементам относятся все поля ввода (input,select,textarea), ссылки, кнопки, фрейм (iframe), тег details, медиаэлементы (video,audio), а также элементы с атрибутами tabindex и contenteditable.
В разных браузерах этот список может отличаться. Наличие внутри <span> фокусируемого элемента не делает сам <span> фокусируемым!

Answer (score 0):

У инпута ведь есть id. А значит правильнее и точнее было бы получать елемент по нему:
`document.getElementById('passp-field-login')`. Тогда можно точно быть уверенным что фокус попадет именно на этот инпут.

Answer (score 0):

Метод [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) позволяет искать элементы по селектору как CSS.

```js
document.querySelector('.Textinput.Textinput_view_big-input.Textinput_size_l .Textinput-Control').focus();
```

```html
<span class="Textinput Textinput_view_big-input Textinput_size_l">
  <input type="text" data-t="field:input-login" dir="ltr" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="username" class="Textinput-Control" id="passp-field-login" name="login" placeholder="Логин или email" value="">
  <span class="Textinput-Box"></span>
</span>
```